# Multiple datepickers with total day fields on the same page

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Need some help with multiple datepickers on the same page!

I'm using two sets of two datepickers that calculate day between the 1st date and the 2nd date.

So basically this, twice:

```
<input type="text" class="datepower" id="datepicker_start" name="from"
        value="">
<input type="text" class="datepower" id="datepicker_end" name="to" value=""
        />
<input type="text" class="datepower" name="totaldays" id="totaldays"
        style="width:80px">days</td>
```

Can't remember where I got the js code (I don't know js) but I eventually got it working for me with some fiddling, only problem is when I try to run the actual page it won't calculate the totals for the one of the total days fields (whichever comes first in the js).

Here's a link to it:
http://jsfiddle.net/lhfiso/vXLtX/1

It may be ugly but it's working! But not when I put it into a live page. I don't know why?!

The code is referenced on a PHP document. I'm using DW CS5.5. PHP version 5.2.14. Anything else you need to know????

Answer (score 0):

first thing that comes to mind is put all your jquery code inside the ready handler like

```
$(function(){
 //your js code
});
```